# Update methods problems

Tags: javascript, database, validation, orm, sequelize.js

I have a problem with the update method. I use Sequelize. I have a validate in my user table. Below is my validate code.

```
validate: {
      hasPasaportOrTcId() {
        // Here we check that at least one of the 'passport' or 'tcId' fields must be filled
        if (!this.passport && !this.tcId) {
          console.log(this,"sdds")
          throw new Error(
            'At least one of the passport or tcId fields must be entered.'
          );
        }
      }
    }
```

When I want to change a user's information, it gives an error and does not update because I did not enter the tcId and passport ID. My update methods:

```
  for (const test of updateTests) {
        try {
          const user= await User.update(test.dataToUpdate, {
            where: test.condition
          })
          console.log(typeof user,"777777");
          const testFields = Object.keys(test.dataToUpdate);
          updateTestResults.push({
            name: test.name,
            result: {
              status: true,
              message: `compare is ${testFields.every(key => {
                return test.dataToUpdate[key] == user[key];
              })}`,
              userId:user.id
            }
          });
        } catch (err) {
        
          updateTestResults.push({
            name: test.name,
            result: {
              status: false,
              message: err.message
            }
          });

        }
      }
```

Help me thank you

Comment: At least we need to look at `test.dataToUpdate` content and the model definition

Comment: If you are not updating neither of `passport` nor `tcId`, you can pass `{ validate:  false }` in the option of `update`. If you want to update either of those, it is tricky with `Model.update`.  This function is an operation against an arbitrary number of rows that some has `passport` value, some has `tcId` value, some both. If you always update to non-null value, this is fine but if you want to update to `{ passport: null }` for those who has both values, then it gets complex.  It could be easier to set this validation in DB side. or on app side by fetching data to validate before update.